# Spring boot - Shutdown endpoint on child (WEB) context doesn't shutdown the parent context

Tags: spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring-Boot 1.1.8-RELEASE.
I'v configured my application to be bootstrap like this:

```
new SpringApplicationBuilder(ParentCtxConfig.class).child(WebCtxConfig.class).web(true).run(args);
```

I've enabled the shutdown endpoint (by setting `endpoints.shutdown.enabled=true` in my application.properties).

The thing is that my application is not being shut down since the parent context is still alive (the shutdown was invoked only on the WEB context).

What I'm doing wrong? I mean, splitting the WEB context from the core context was a bad practice? If not, how do I shutdown the core context?

Comment: What is the parent context doing? It's probably got a non-daemon thread running, so if you can get rid of that it should just stop.

Comment: I don't see the parent context shutdown being called, is it supposed to be invoked? As far as I understand it , the shutdown endpoint applied only on the WEB context, isn't it?

Comment: To your question/answer, what's keep on running is a simple scheduled task. The scheduler is a bean in the parent context, I just don't see the scheduler's destroy method being invoked(that is how I came to the conclusion that the parent context is not being shutdown)

Comment: I think you have found a missing feature. It wouldn't be correct to unconditionally close the parent context (it might have other children that are still running). But you might need to be able to elect to have it closed.

Comment: So, if I understand you correctly, there should be a way to tell the child context, whether the parent context should be closed or not. In addition all of the children will be closed when the parent is closed. So, until we have that feature, what's your recommendation?

Comment: Actualy, I just checked and the `ShutdownEndpoint` should be created in the parent context, and it should just work (TM). Can you verify that the endpoint is in the parent for you? What version of Spring Boot are you using?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65972/discussion-between-modi-and-dave-syer).